Find all such polynomials satisfying a condition

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$ be a polynomial satisfying
the following conditions:
(i) $\{a_0,a_1,...,a_n\}$ is a permutation
of $\{0,1,2,...,n\}$.
(ii) $P(x)$ has $n$ roots which are all real
numbers.
a) Prove that $P(0)=0$.
b) Find all such polynomials

Part a) follows easily from the Descartes' rule of signs. Since $P(x)$ doesn't have positive real roots, if $P(0)\ne0$ then $P(x)$ must have $n$ negative real roots (counting with multiplicity) so $P(-x)$ must have $n$ positive roots, but it only has $n-2$ sign changes.
I don't know how to deal with part b). Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

What's the source of this problem? It seems like a contest problem.

@Ѕᴀᴀᴅ yes, but let's just concentrate on the problem.

See Include source / motivation for your question for justifications to do so :]

this problem seems hard

I can solve part (b). Are you still interested in seeing a solution? If so, I recommend that you repost your question as a new question, with your solution to part (a) included as part of your post. Also, to avoid having the new question closed for lack of context, you should identify the contest from which the problem originated, and you should include some work of your own (an attempt) at solving part (b).
